# Exp:resso Store Payment Gateway changes

Tags: expresso-store, devdemon, payment-gateway

In a recent version of Exp:resso Store since (2.3.1) there has been a change in what information gets passed to the Payment Gateways (I believe using the function getDescription();).

In 2.3.1 the OrderID was passed, in both 2.5.0 and 2.5.1 it is the Cart ID that is passed (now these are separate things). This is paying havoc with my client accounting team, who now have no obvious way to tally Payments (on both SagePay and Paypal Express) with the orders.

Is this a bug, or designed behaviour? If designed behaviour is there a way I can get the order ID on the AuthoriseRequest.php scripts please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version of Store as of 2.5+ Carts and Orders are now separate database tables. This allows for sequential order ids and also more control over what you can do with carts for marketing automation.

So now an order id is not generated until after the completion of the payment. So only cart ids are passed to the gateway. The order id will be different on its return from the gateway.